# how to attach a range/input slider onto a canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am aiming to attach a slider onto this codepen animation, so the user can edit the speed of the animation.

At the moment, I am not getting any errors, but I am not getting the value from the input slider passed through to the animation.

```
   this.speed     = dotSpeed;
```

I am aiming to take the value from the slider, create a variable and put it through the "function Circle" properties.

```js
var dotArray = [];

function threeDotSliderChangeSpeed (value) {
                    document.getElementById('threeDotSpeed').innerHTML = value;
                    dotSpeed = +value;   // + will convert the string to number
                for (var i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++) {
                    dotArray[i].speed = Math.round(1 * dotSpeed);
                }
            }
            

 var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas2' ),
  c = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
  i = 0,
  rowOne = [],
  rowTwo = [],
  rowThree = [],
  length = canvas.width * 0.4,
  origin = [ canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 ],
  angle = 90,
        dotSpeed = 2,
  loop;

 function Circle( args ) {
  this.position  = [ 0, 0 ];
  this.angle     = 30;
  this.speed     = dotSpeed;
  this.offset    = 1;
  this.length    = 100;
  this.size      = 5;
  this.color     = '#fff';
  this.direction = 'grow';

  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.position )
   this.position = args.position;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.angle )
   this.angle = args.angle;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.speed )
   this.speed = args.speed;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.length )
   this.length = args.length;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.size )
   this.size = args.size;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.color )
   this.color = args.color;
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.offset ) {
   this.offset = args.offset;
   this.length = canvas.width * this.offset * 0.03
  }
 }

 Circle.prototype.render = function() {
  this.move();
  this.draw();
 }

 Circle.prototype.draw = function() {
  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc( this.position[0], this.position[1], ( this.size / 2 ), 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();
 }

 Circle.prototype.move = function() {
  this.angle = ( this.angle < 360 ) ? this.angle + this.speed : 0;

  if ( 'grow' == this.direction ) {
   this.length++;
   this.direction = ( 150 >= this.length ) ? 'grow' : 'shrink';
  } else {
   this.length--;
   this.direction = ( 50 <= this.length ) ? 'shrink' : 'grow';
  }

  this.position[0] = this.length * Math.sin( this.angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );
  this.position[1] = this.length * Math.cos( this.angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );

  this.position[0] = this.position[0] + origin[0];
  this.position[1] = this.position[1] + origin[1];
 }

 for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
  var offset = 1;
  rowOne.push( new Circle( {
   angle: 0,
   offset: i
  } ) );
  rowTwo.push( new Circle( {
   angle: 120,
   offset: i
  } ) );
  rowThree.push( new Circle( {
   angle: 240,
   offset: i
  } ) );
 }

 function render() {
  c.fillStyle = 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.025 )';
  c.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
   rowOne[i].render();
   rowTwo[i].render();
   rowThree[i].render();
  }
 }

 (function animate() {
  render();
  loop = setTimeout( animate, 40 );
 })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - 3 dotted-line canvas animation.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
     <p id="attribute">Speed </p>
     <span id="threeDotSpeed" class="sliderSpan">5</span>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" onchange="threeDotSliderChangeSpeed(3)"/>
     <br /> <br />
     <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a video of another one I got going, using the same method.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjZ6CfQ2WrY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value from the slider you need to get the value from the element
by using `document.getElementById('rg').value` on change event

js:

```
var dotArray = [];

function threeDotSliderChangeSpeed () {
    var value = document.getElementById('rg').value;
    alert(value);
    document.getElementById('threeDotSpeed').innerHTML = value;
    dotSpeed = +value;   // + will convert the string to number
    for (var i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++) {
        dotArray[i].speed = Math.round(1 * dotSpeed);
    }
}


var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas2' ),
    c = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
    i = 0,
    rowOne = [],
    rowTwo = [],
    rowThree = [],
    length = canvas.width * 0.4,
    origin = [ canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 ],
    angle = 90,
    dotSpeed = 2,
    loop;

function Circle( args ) {
    this.position  = [ 0, 0 ];
    this.angle     = 30;
    this.speed     = dotSpeed;
    this.offset    = 1;
    this.length    = 100;
    this.size      = 5;
    this.color     = '#fff';
    this.direction = 'grow';

    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.position )
        this.position = args.position;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.angle )
        this.angle = args.angle;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.speed )
        this.speed = args.speed;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.length )
        this.length = args.length;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.size )
        this.size = args.size;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.color )
        this.color = args.color;
    if ( 'undefined' !== typeof args.offset ) {
        this.offset = args.offset;
        this.length = canvas.width * this.offset * 0.03
    }
}

Circle.prototype.render = function() {
    this.move();
    this.draw();
}

Circle.prototype.draw = function() {
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc( this.position[0], this.position[1], ( this.size / 2 ), 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
}

Circle.prototype.move = function() {
    this.angle = ( this.angle < 360 ) ? this.angle + this.speed : 0;

    if ( 'grow' == this.direction ) {
        this.length++;
        this.direction = ( 150 >= this.length ) ? 'grow' : 'shrink';
    } else {
        this.length--;
        this.direction = ( 50 <= this.length ) ? 'shrink' : 'grow';
    }

    this.position[0] = this.length * Math.sin( this.angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );
    this.position[1] = this.length * Math.cos( this.angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );

    this.position[0] = this.position[0] + origin[0];
    this.position[1] = this.position[1] + origin[1];
}

for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var offset = 1;
    rowOne.push( new Circle( {
        angle: 0,
        offset: i
    } ) );
    rowTwo.push( new Circle( {
        angle: 120,
        offset: i
    } ) );
    rowThree.push( new Circle( {
        angle: 240,
        offset: i
    } ) );
}

function render() {
    c.fillStyle = 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.025 )';
    c.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
        rowOne[i].render();
        rowTwo[i].render();
        rowThree[i].render();
    }
}

(function animate() {
    render();
    loop = setTimeout( animate, 40 );
})();
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CodePen - 3 dotted-line canvas animation.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <p id="attribute">Speed </p>
        <span id="threeDotSpeed" class="sliderSpan">5</span>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" id="rg" onchange="threeDotSliderChangeSpeed(3)"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am able to get the slider value on alert 
you can see output in codepin
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOOjXE

Comment: Now to make the slider responsive.. I guess to make the slider value responsive and actually update the canvas animation, I would somehow need to use js to tell the canvas to re-draw every time the slider value is changed. Any tips for how to have a crack at this?

Comment: you can call render on slider change listener may be that would help.

Comment: try changing the timeout interval as per the slider speed

Comment: Check in this code pluck u need to change the time interval as per you speed requirement you can see in this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGGMxx

Comment: Thats epic. Thanks for that!